# Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="s", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0) Web3.js

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to call using web3.js a read-only methods, but I'm having the following error:

```
Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="s", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

This is the code I use to call the method:

```
signedContract.methods.getEnabledCurrencies().call().then(console.log)
```

While the following is the ABI of my method:

```
 {  type: 'function',
    name: 'getEnabledCurrencies',
    constant: true,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    payable: false,
    inputs: [],
    outputs: [ [Object] ]
  }
```

The function on the smart contract is the following:

```
function getEnabledCurrencies() public view returns (string[] memory) {
    return currencyNames;
}
```

I can use the same signedContract object to call state changing methods without any problems.

Comment: Which compiler version?

Comment: do you mean solc? Then it's 0.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing outputs in the ABI to:

```
"outputs": [
    {
        "internalType": "string[]",
        "name": "",
        "type": "string[]"
    }
]
```

Comment: It worked. Can you provide me an explanation of this? I'll accept your question

Comment: Well, I don’t know what generates your ABI, for me this was the output and it seemed more correct than the one you posted. I use truffle.

Comment: I generate it using ethers.js. In fact I've problems only using web3 not ethers.js. Maybe that's could explain the problem.